# playing youtube videos in android application

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to play YouTube stream in my application .

Embedding YouTube player  (YouTube Api's)provides me an setting kind of  option where the video can be directed to the YouTube page

Is there any other way where android native players can play YouTube videos on the surface view

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

try this ;)

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

it's a tutorial with an android project to play youtube video in android app.

good day ;)